# PROMETHEUS: Load custom alert rules from custom ConfigMap

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I'm trying to figure out how to load custom alert rules into Prometheus from a custom ConfigMap.  I have found bits and pieces on the internet, including on YouTube, about loading custom rules from a file, but everything I've found seems to assume a lot of prior knowledge/expertise in helm, prometheus, kubernetes, yaml, etc.  So far, I haven't been able to fill in the gaps so that I can get something working with either a custom rules file or a custom ConfigMap with our rules in it.  Out preference would be to get it working with a custom ConfigMap.

We are using Helm to create our yaml and then using kubectl to apply it as follows:

```
helm template monitoring \
  --namespace monitoring \
  prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --version 41.5.1 \
  -f extra_values.yaml \
  --set grafana.smtp.existingSecret=grafana-smtp \
  --set grafana.adminPassword=${GRAFANA_ADMIN_PASSWORD} \
  --set grafana.ingress.hosts=\{grafana.${ROOT_DNS}\} \
  --set prometheus.ingress.hosts=\{prometheus.${ROOT_DNS}\} \
  | kubectl -n monitoring apply -f-
```

My latest attempt was to add the following to our extra_values.yaml file:

```
configmapReload:
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
    extraConfigmapMounts:
       - name: soti-alerts
         mountPath: /etc/prometheus/rules/soti-alerts
         configMap: soti-alerts
         readOnly: false
```

But I still see that the init-config-reloader for prometheus is only monitoring /etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-monitoring-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0 (see below):

```
│ Init Containers:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│   init-config-reloader:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│     Container ID:  docker://64b32c7e59acdfa5ea565a85480155ab2e49984710685f165dafa8e5f195acc2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│     Image:         quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.60.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│     Image ID:      docker-pullable://quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader@sha256:b0451875cef3b0ac63bc786ad90527bfdc368763b4f9954bf4c8182472554a5a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│     Port:          8080/TCP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│     Host Port:     0/TCP                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                │
│     Command:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│       /bin/prometheus-config-reloader                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   │
│     Args:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               │
│       --watch-interval=0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                │
│       --listen-address=:8080                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│       --config-file=/etc/prometheus/config/prometheus.yaml.gz                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│       --config-envsubst-file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│       --watched-dir=/etc/prometheus/rules/prometheus-monitoring-kube-prometheus-prometheus-rulefiles-0
```

Can you please provide some guidance on how to set things up so that I can have prometheus monitor a custom ConfigMap for our custom alert rules?  Can you point me to a website or youtube video that describes this step by step?  Thanks in advance!